# Python 2.7: Evaluating pairs in a 2D Python Array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
myarray = array([[Me, False], [Me, True], [Partner, False], [Me, True], [Me, False],[Me, True],[Partner, True]])
```

What I'm trying to do is to start a counter each time [Me, True] appears and have that counter increment until either [Partner, True] or [Partner, False] appears in the array. Each time this counter runs into [Partner, True] or [Partner, False] it should reset.

so, if permcount = 0 and tempcount = 0,

In the example above since [Me, True] appears right before [Partner, False], tempcount would increment to 1, then get added to permcount when [Partner, False] is encountered and reset to 0.

Now permcount = 1 and tempcount = 0

When [Me, True] appears next, tempcount would reach 3 before encountering [Partner, True] and resetting to 0 and permcount = 4.

My code looks like this:

```
tempcount = 0
permcount = []
flag = True
initiated = False

for x,y in myarray:
    if x == "Me" and y == True:
        if flag == True:
            tempcount = tempcount + 1
            initiated == True
        else:
            tempcount = 0
            tempcount = tempcount + 1
            flag == True
    if x == "Me" and y == False and flag == True and initiated == True:
        tempcount = tempcount + 1
    if x == "Partner" and y == True and flag == True and initiated == True:
        permcount.append(tempcount)
        flag == False
    if x == "Partner" and y == False and flag == True and initiated == True:      
        permcount.append(tempcount)
        flag == False
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to evaluate and append tempcount at all as permcount is still empty at the end. Any recommendations of what I'm doing incorrectly?

EDIT: Indeed this is not a Numpy array... I achieved this list of lists through a pandas dataframe.values command. Also corrected some typos for any users who will see this later. Thank you guys!

-Mano

Comment: I don't see any use of `numpy` arrays here; which is good because `np.append` does not work like the list append.  Also with values like "Me' and `True` a list, or list of lists is better than arrays.  As for the problem - you need to print some intermediate results.

Comment: Can you provide some expected output?

Comment: `initiated == True` should be `initiated = True`, and ditto for `Flag == True`

Comment: It also looks like you can maybe replace most of your work here with `itertools.groupby(..., key=lambda x: x == (Me, True))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I changed the array to

```
 alist = [["Me", False], ["Me", True],...
```

Without further change I get 3 for `tempcount` and `[]` for `permcount`.

Changing those misplaced `==` to `=`, the ones that are meant to change the value of `flag` and `intiated` (as opposed to test them), I get

```
3
[1, 3]
```

The `== True` like expressions can be simplified (though it doesn't change the results)

```
for x,y in alist:
    if x == "Me" and y:
        if flag:
            tempcount += 1
            initiated = True
        else:
            tempcount = 1
            flag = True
    if x == "Me" and not y and flag and initiated:
        tempcount += 1
    if x == "Partner" and y and flag and initiated:
        permcount.append(tempcount)
        flag = False
    if x == "Partner" and not y and flag and initiated:      
        permcount.append(tempcount)
        flag = False
```

Comment: ah! Damn I didn't realize the difference between == and =. Thank you so much that worked like a charm! Mano